Restrict Chromebook settings Access
I have chromebooks in a classroom setting. The trainees use chromebooks in guest mode. I’m looking to be able to restrict the access to setting for the guest account so they can’t change language. I can only see how to shut down the whole account. I have access to the ”admin” account so access on my end shouldn’t be an issue.
I’ve looked in the service settings as well as accounts and can’t find what I’m looking for
